# Python: Slicing string in three-character substrings

Tags: python, string, for-loop, slice

I am attempting to slice a string into triplets based on the characters like this:

```
string1 = 'abcdef'
substrings = 'abc', 'bcd', 'cde', 'def'
```

I then want to compare these 'triplets to a second string and count their occurrence:

```
string2 = 'abcijk'
substrings of string1 in string2 = 1 ('abc').
```

I am trying to do this using a function:

```
def HowManyTriplets(s1, s2):
n = 0
    for c in s1:
        print c + c[:2]
    if c in s1 is c in s2:
        n = n + 1
return n
```

This code does not work because c[:2] does not get the two characters following any c (s1[:2] simply appends the first two characters of s1).

How can I solve this to append the two characters that follow a character c to c, for example c = c + d + e

Comment: Yes, they must be in order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
def subs():
    string1 = 'abcdef'
    string2 = 'abcijk'
    subs = [string1[s:s+3] for s in range(len(string1)) if len(string1[s:s+3]) > 2]
    for s in subs:
        print s, string2.count(s)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to just use slice notation in a for-loop:

```
for i in xrange(len(s1) - 2):
    c = s1[i:i+3]
    # do various operations here with c
```

Alternatively collect them in a list comprehension:

```
list1 = [s1[i:i+3] for i in xrange(len(s1) - 2)]
n = 0
for c in list1:
    if c in s2:
        n += 1
print n
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're gonna need to get the substrings for two different strings (your `string1` and `string2`), I'd move that slicing into a very simple function:

```
def substring(string):
   return [ string[i:i+3] for i in range(len(string)) if i + 3 <= len(string) ]
```

To compare and count, you can use the [list.count](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) method and combine it with your recently created `substring` function:

```
string1 = 'abcdef'
string2 = 'abcijk'
[ (substr, substring(string2).count(substr)) for substr in substring(string1) ]
```

Which outputs:

```
[('abc', 1), ('bcd', 0), ('cde', 0), ('def', 0)]
```